# How to remove manually installed Python version in opt?

Tags: python, uninstall, opt

I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu, and I recently followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYUH08BM37g as part of a course for learning Python, and no longer need it. I was never able to use it or create an interpreter for Pycharm with it anyways, even though I could do so with the other versions of Python, so it's just dead weight on my computer.

We've now switched to more current versions of Python, and I've tried searching for how to uninstall it from Computer/opt, but the guides I'm finding only show me how to uninstall the more recent versions. I also found it strange that this version would be located in a different place than all the other Python versions. Obviously when I try to simply delete the folder and tgz, the option is not there and I cannot remove them or move them to a different location.

Any help on removing it is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It is unlikely that the volunteers in this site will watch the whole youtube video to figure out what all changes you made. So, please help us help you by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1435799/edit) the post the with commands you had executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for python, but in most cases, software installed into /opt will be completely installed there and maybe nowhere else. But first you should look for an uninstall script in the top level directory /opt/python or similar.
And maybe there is a README file (or INSTALL), which explains how to do it. If you can't find anything, I would remove the directory - probably you need sudo rights to do it. `whereis python` (or python3) might have helped you in finding out, whether other dirs are affected, but switching to another version will have made it hard, to find out, to which version which file belongs, if they are intermixed. The file date might help.

```
sudo find /opt/python -delete
```

is a command, to remove the whole directory structure in /opt, if installed with sudo permission.

The name might be /opt/python3 or similar.